# javascript/jQuery not working properly in Firefox/IE when submitting form

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, firefox, model-view-controller

I have a form generated within MVC razor for moving Contacts between list boxes (Assigned and Unassigned).

I am using jQuery to move the `<option>` elements between the list boxes and then  bind them using the `selected` attribute when the form is submitted.

```
@model SiteAssignmentViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ListBox("AvailableContacts", new SelectList(Model.Contacts.Where(p => !Model.SelectedContactIDs.Contains(p.ID)), "ID", "FullName"))
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value=">" onclick="MoveListBoxItems('AvailableContacts', '@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedContactIDs)');" />
    <input type="button" value="<" onclick="MoveListBoxItems('@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedContactIDs)', 'AvailableContacts');" />
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedContactIDs, new SelectList(Model.Contacts.Where(p => Model.SelectedContactIDs.Contains(p.ID)), "ID", "FullName"))
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" onclick="BindListBoxItems('@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedContactIDs)');" />
}

<script>
    function MoveListBoxItems(fromListBox, toListBox) {
        $("#" + fromListBox).find("option:selected").appendTo($("#" + toListBox));
        $("#" + toListBox).find("option").attr("selected", false);
    }

    function BindListBoxItems(listBox) {
        $("#" + listBox).find("option").attr("selected", true);
    };
</script>
```

When using Chrome its workperfectly, you see the options being selected on the view then submitted to the server.

In Firefox and IE however, the function is called but the selected attribute is not appended before the form is submitted. If I change the button type to `button` all the options are selected as expected (except now the form will not submit). I have tried wrapping the form submit in the same method as follows:

```
<input type="submit" value="OK" onclick="SubmitForm('@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedContactIDs)');" />
<script>
    function SubmitForm() {
        $("#" + listBox).find("option").attr("selected", true);
        $("#contactsForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```

This has made no difference to the behaviour in Firefox, I get no warning issues on the console or any binding errors on the server. When using the element inspector it seems the attributes are simply not appended before the form submit.

Can anyone explain this behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried making sure the DOM is ready before applying your code - $(document).ready(function(){ .. )); - http://api.jquery.com/ready/ - ??

Comment: I thought $(document).ready(function) was only used when the page is loading. Can this also be used in this scenario?

Comment: the ready() method makes sure the DOM is ready before running your code inside it.. or you can put your JS at the bottom of the page before the ending BODY tag .. since your using inline javascript events on tags its best to make sure the DOM is ready or have your JS at the bottom of the page

Comment: I would love to know why this question deserves a downvote! Pretty sure the the problem is clearly explained and demonstrates my attempts to resolve the problem myself before asking the overflow community.

Comment: who down voted your question?, im not seeing a downvote.. looks like they took it back.. your question was valid!

Comment: I don't know how to check who, the activity just says +5/-2 and reputation has done down 4 points.

Comment: Are you suggesting `functiom Submit(){ //bind; $(document).ready(function() { $("form").submit(); }); }` ??

Answer (score 0):

you can just use click event on the submit button. I cant see all your HTML markup, but:

```
<input type="submit" value="OK" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("input[type='submit']").bind("click", function(){

      // code would go here
      SubmitForm();

      return false;
   });

   function SubmitForm() {
       $("#" + listBox).find("option").attr("selected", true);
       $("#contactsForm").submit();
   }

});
</script>
```

You could also try  $("form").submit();

Comment: This has not worked, same behaviour. My html mark-up is exactly the same as what I have written in the question.